# Can you troubleshoot this card with slide up effect on hover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple Bootstrap card and I would like to slide up the card content to display a longer paragraph on mouse hover-over:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row my-5 d-flex justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="card">

        <!-- Card image -->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1546251/pexels-photo-1546251.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">

        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body close text-center">

          <!-- Title -->
          <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold pt-1 pb-2"><a>A word about art</a></h4>
          <!-- Text -->
          <p class="card-text my-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <!-- Button -->
          <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/products/jquery-ui-kit/" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded blue-gradient">Wanna some art? <i class="fas fa-palette ml-2"></i></a>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Card -->

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

And this is my JS:

```
$('.card').mouseover(function() {
  $('.card-body').toggleClass('close');
});
```

It's working but with a funky behavior on mouse hover over.  Here's a fiddle to preview: https://jsfiddle.net/uL719afz/

Where did I go wrong with **mouseover** and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're toggling the class on and off whenever the mouseover event fires, without considering whether the mouse is still in (or has left) the element. Use `.hover` instead:

```
$('.card').hover(
  () => $('.card-body').removeClass('close'),
  () => $('.card-body').addClass('close')
);
```

```js
$('.card').hover(
  () => $('.card-body').removeClass('close'),
  () => $('.card-body').addClass('close')
);
```

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}
.card {
  border-radius:.35rem !important;
}
.card img {
  border-radius:.35rem !important;
}
.card-body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 1s;
  border-radius:.35rem !important;
}
.card-text {
  color: #2b0099 !important;
}
.card-body.close {
    top: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    margin-top: -5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius:.35rem !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius:.35rem !important;
    opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row my-5 d-flex justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="card">

        <!-- Card image -->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1546251/pexels-photo-1546251.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">

        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body close text-center">

          <!-- Title -->
          <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold pt-1 pb-2"><a>A word about art</a></h4>
          <!-- Text -->
          <p class="card-text my-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <!-- Button -->
          <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/products/jquery-ui-kit/" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded blue-gradient">Wanna some art? <i class="fas fa-palette ml-2"></i></a>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Card -->

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

But I think it would be more elegant to avoid JS altogether, and use `:hover` CSS instead: instead of the lack of `.close`, use `.card:hover .card-body`:

```
.card-body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 1s;
  border-radius: .35rem !important;
  top: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  margin-top: -5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .35rem !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .35rem !important;
  opacity: .9;
}

.card:hover .card-body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ndLuvzy/